# How to query data within a group using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks something like this which has been grouped and assigned a group number

Example:

```
groupnumber userid  username    borrower name
1            1       userA        A
1            1       userA        B
2            2       userB        C
2            2       userB        D
2            3       userC        D
```

In this example I have shown group number 1 to be desired results. Each group should only have one user Id (multiple entries is fine) but can have different borrower names. <--- This group I want to keep

For group two where there are different userids within the group I need that group to be completely removed from the list or just queried so I can flag as conflicted data group

I got the first part of this set up so the groups are being shown but the second part I cant seem to figure out. Any help would be appreciate it

Basically I would like to write a query so that the table will yield this result

```
groupnumber userid  username    borrower name
1            1       userA        A
1            1       userA        B
```

Thus removing groupnumber 2 all together since the userid werent all the same in the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that code got befluxtifitated when I posted it.  I will try Ye Olde Markuppe Editorre to see if I can fix it:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE GROUPNUMBER IN (
  SELECT GROUPNUMBER
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE COUNT( DISTINCT USERNAME ) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks again.. very useful with count distinct username. I can start using this for the other situations I have as well

Comment: You can't have an aggregate inside a `where` clause the way you have it here.  Did you test the query?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write a query that returns the rows where groups have a single `userid`:

```
select *
  from tbl
 where groupnumber in (select groupnumber
                         from tbl
                        group by groupnumber
                       having count(distinct userid) = 1)
```

If you want to actually delete the rows where the groups have multiple userids so that the table is only left with the rows you are interested in:

```
delete tbl
 where groupnumber in (select groupnumber
                         from tbl
                        group by groupnumber
                       having count(distinct userid) > 1)
```